# OAuth token submitted with the request can not be parsed

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365api

I'm trying to implement a client that imports the events that a user has in Office 365 so that I can easily display them in the company's application.

I managed to get the user to authenticate with his / her Office 365 account and to approve my application and to also get an AccessToken, but when I try to use the token to retrieve the events from the API, I get a 401 HTTP error code, no body and in the headers I have this:

```
Content-Length →0
Date →Thu, 17 Mar 2016 08:56:00 GMT
Server →Microsoft-IIS/8.0
WWW-Authenticate →Bearer client_id="00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*", token_types="app_asserted_user_v1 service_asserted_app_v1", authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize", error="invalid_token",Basic Realm="",Basic Realm=""
X-BEServer →DB4PR06MB522
X-BackEndHttpStatus →401
X-CalculatedBETarget →DB4PR06MB522.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com
X-DiagInfo →DB4PR06MB522
X-FEServer →AM3PR06CA022
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
request-id →de1963bc-36df-4473-81f6-66ec37e8b415
x-ms-diagnostics →2000001;reason="OAuth token submitted with the request can not be parsed.";error_category="invalid_token"
```

The token I get from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token with the following body:

```
grant_type=authorization_code
redirect_uri=https://example.com/redirect-uri
client_id=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
client_secret=[my-client-secret]
code=[code-received-from-user-auth]
```

The token I receive from the above call, I send through the Authorization header to https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events like so:

```
Authorization: Bearer [access-token]
```

The response status I get from this call is 401 Unauthorized, I get an empty body and the headers are like so:

```
Content-Length →0
Date →Thu, 17 Mar 2016 08:56:00 GMT
Server →Microsoft-IIS/8.0
WWW-Authenticate →Bearer client_id="00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*", token_types="app_asserted_user_v1 service_asserted_app_v1", authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize", error="invalid_token",Basic Realm="",Basic Realm=""
X-BEServer →DB4PR06MB522
X-BackEndHttpStatus →401
X-CalculatedBETarget →DB4PR06MB522.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com
X-DiagInfo →DB4PR06MB522
X-FEServer →AM3PR06CA022
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
request-id →de1963bc-36df-4473-81f6-66ec37e8b415
x-ms-diagnostics →2000001;reason="OAuth token submitted with the request can not be parsed.";error_category="invalid_token"
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem I had.

For future reference, the problem was that I wasn't telling the https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token endpoint what I needed the token for.

I had to provide a resource parameter with the base url of the resource I was going to interogate after.
In my case, it was https://outlook.office365.com.

Comment: Hi, i am facing same issue. can you tell me in detail what should i do. Thanks

Comment: It's been a long time since I did that, but I think you also need to pass a `resource=[resource-endpoint]` in the body sent to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token.