# Outlook API invalid_token error

Tags: outlook-restapi

I'm trying to call the outlook API with the following request:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars
GET
Authorization: Bearer [my fresh bearer token]
```

I successfully retrieved an access_token from the token endpoint after the login and user consent.

However, every request I try returns 401 Unauthorized with the following header (showing that one cause it looks weird to me):

```
WwwAuthenticate [HttpHeaderValueCollection]: {Bearer client_id="00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*", token_types="app_asserted_user_v1 service_asserted_app_v1", authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize", error="invalid_token", Basic Realm="", Basic Realm="", Basic Realm=""}
```

As you can see, at the end there is error="invalid_token"

Also, there is app_asserted_user_v1 service_asserted_app_v1

Is there something I forgot to activate or configure properly?

EDIT: I did found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36056964/oauth-token-submitted-with-the-request-can-not-be-parsed) but if I add a resource parameter like the OP, I get "Bad Request" and this code:

> AADSTS90100: The 'resource' request parameter is not supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All right I found the answer myself and I hope it will help more people:

The problem was even before, at the step I was redirecting the user to the MS Login page.

At that point I used to give it the following scopes:

> openid Calendars.ReadWrite offline_access profile

BUT, the Calendars.ReadWrite MUST but passed with its "full" name, being:

> https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.ReadWrite

HTH